# Base64 with bad characters

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, base64

I wrote some `Angular` web app and I need to display images with `ngFor` so I connected my app with `MySQL database` with `Blob` photo value:

[image: db structure]

And here is my `node.js WebApi` code responsible for sending data:

```js
Przepis.getAll = result => {
    sql.query("SELECT id,title,description,author,recipe,preparation,TO_BASE64(photo) FROM przepisy", (err, res) => {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log("error: ", err);
            result(null, err);
            return; 
        }
        console.log("Przepisy: ", res);
        result(null, res);
    });
};
```

Only problem I have is that this Base64 string that I get from Api has some defects like `\n` and `\` characters:

[image: Base64 repair]

Any ideas why? (Thanks for any response)

Comment: Have you tried stripping the newlines out before decoding? How did you get this with literal `\n` in it?

Comment: You mean deleting \ n back when it was a blob, after TO_BASE64 () encoding done in MySQL or when sending it via api? And this \ n I have no idea where it is from, I think it arises after using TO_BASE64 () because there were already these tags in the console log.

Comment: It shouldn't be literal backslash-n, it should be an actual newline, so it's peculiar that you're getting random junk like that. Maybe an error in decoding? Or something double-encodes it somewhere? That could be an artifact of JSON-in-JSON.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue fixed on backend side by modifying SQL Query to removing new line chars `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Use btoa() and atob() to decode and encode Base64 from and to ANCII